# Dragging Pegman in Maps V3 triggers unwanted click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have two event handlers on a V3 map with linked Streetview. (Linked using     map.setStreetView(panorama);) One is to detect a single click on the map, in which case I update an HTML field to show the lat/long of that point. Another is to detect the location of the panorama being changed (position_changed) so I can update an HTML field to show the lat/long of the panorama.

The problem is when I change the panorama by dragging the pegman, the click event is triggered when I release the mouse button. As a result both sets of fields in the HTML get changed instead of just the panorama location one.

I tried to stop it by testing the current and previous panorama positions when the click event happens, but it seems that the panorama position changed event triggers just before the click event, meaning both the previous and current positions of the panorama are already set to the new location.

I tried changing the single click event to a double click, but that also causes the map to zoom in, which I do not want.

What I basically want is for the click event not to trigger if it is caused by the pegman being dragged, or some way of detecting that he was just dragged. I guess one way would be to store the time of the last panorama change in the position_change event, then check how long ago that was when the click event is triggered, but that seems a bit hacky.

This is the code of my two events:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {    
    document.getElementById('mappos').innerHTML = e.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) + "," + e.latLng.lng().toFixed(6);    
 });

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
      streetvpos = panorama.getPosition();
      document.getElementById('svpos').innerHTML = streetvpos.lat().toFixed(6) + "," + streetvpos.lng().toFixed(6);
  });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjyh423s/2/)

For the benefit of others I have come up with a working solution. I did some testing and found that on a typical pegman drag the click event triggers almost immediately but the panorama position change event takes about 250ms to trigger. I therefore use a timer in the click event handler to delay it 1 second then check how long since a pano change occurred. Typically it is about 750ms ago. If it is more than 2 seconds I assumes this was a genuine click and not a pegman move.

```
var lastsvchg = 0; // at the top
// ...

    // add a click event handler to give lat/long. Have to cater for the fact that dragging the streetview pegman also triggers a click event
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            setTimeout(function() {  // wait 0.5 seconds to let pano_changed trigger first in case pegman being dragged
                if (new Date() - lastsvchg > 2000) {  // ignore if due to pegman being dragged in last 2 seconds
                    document.getElementById('mappos').innerHTML = e.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) + "," + e.latLng.lng().toFixed(6);
                }
            }, 1000);  // wait 1 second before testing
     });

// detect changes to streetview position. Could use position_changed event also.
      google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pano_changed', function() {
          lastsvchg = new Date(); // to check if click event triggered by pegman move
          svpos = panorama.getPosition();
          document.getElementById('svpos').innerHTML = svpos.lat().toFixed(6) + "," + svpos.lng().toFixed(6);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just bind the click event to the map container or did you use the proper function `google.maps.event.trigger()' for each click event?

You can check the source of [this](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html) page, at http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html

Comment: All of my clicking is taking place on the map. I am not touching the streetview pane. My click event starts like this:       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {

Comment: I copied the code from the page you refer to above and added a panorama to the so it would put the pegman on the map. Sure enough when I drag him the click event is triggered on button-up.

Comment: I tried to set up a fiddle to demonstrate the change to the above page, here: http://jsfiddle.net/yjyh423s/ but it is my first fiddle and I cannot get it to work. Maybe someone else can so the issue can be demonstrated. I added the 9 lines of code midway down the Javascript section starting with var svpos=

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjyh423s/2/) (added to your question as well)

Comment: Thank you for fixing the fiddle. I have added a working solution to my question but would still prefer something more elegant.